# Lecture notes in complex algebraic geometry (which might follow Voisin's book)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I have two questions here,

- Whats the difference in the target audience/required-background between Voisin's two volumes and Griffiths-Harris' book on algebraic geometry which also seems highly tied to the complex world?
- Are there any course notes which follow either of the above two books? (I found this one but it seems too short to be have been a full course, [http://www.imar.ro/~dmatei/snsb/hodge.pdf](http://www.imar.ro/%7Edmatei/snsb/hodge.pdf) )

---

- One course notes I have seen related to the above is this
  [http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/calgeom.pdf](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ejean/calgeom.pdf)
- And there is this other book on similar topics,

  [https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~fouad.elzein/Hodge.pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Efouad.elzein/Hodge.pdf)